# React native trigger/simulate touch event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, event-handling, touch-event

How do I simulate the touch event in React native?

Basically I have X and Y cordinates of an onPress event and want to trigger a touch event at the same position again.

This is doable in javascript

```
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

But doable in RN?

Comment: With ADB you can try with `adb shell input tap x y`. But i dont think this will help you since it's not a module. (I'm searching something for you)

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior thanks. I would like to simulate the event from a component.

Comment: I imagined so...